# How to replace cell content for a row of cells vs writing to each cell

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y5WO.jpg)Instead of a looping condition that writes to each cell in one row, what method can I use that works on the entire row that searches and replaces all cells with a blank if it contains a portion of a string like "OPC1.Object..."

Currently using a loop where the 1st loop iteration leaves 1 cell untouched, but not required:

```
enter code here
      For i = 0 To sTemplateType.Extension.Count - 1      
         If sBaseTagExtension <> sTemplateType.Extension(i) Then
             sXlCellName = sTemplateType.WireTemplateColumnLetter(i) & Trim(Str(iCurrentRow))
             ws.Cells.Range(sXlCellName).Value = ""
         Else
            Continue For
         End If`
      Next
```

Comment: You might want to add an excel tag. I looked at this not knowing what kind of cells you wanted to update. Cells in a DataGridView? a GridView? a DataTable? Also are you using Excel automation of Ado.net. I guess it is the automation.

Comment: No, just cells with text in a worksheet. Not Ado.Net  using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace in VB.NET with visual studio.